# An answer only if all records have the same value

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple table:

```
id | from | tu | status_os1 | status_os2
```

`status_os1` and `status_os2` can be only `paid` or `unpaid`.

I want to show a message `"You have all dues paid"`.

So my question is - what should I write in the `SQL` part to give an answer only if all records have values `"paid"`?

I was trying do it in below way but it also failed:

```
$rezultat = $polacz->query("SELECT case when COUNT(status_os1) = 0 then 1 end FROM skladki WHERE status_os1='unpaid'");
$wynik = $rezultat->num_rows;
if($wynik>0)
{
    echo "You have all dues paid";
}
```

Comment: `select count(*) from table where status_os1 = "paid" and status_os2 = "paid"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this from the opposite side: you give the message if none of the rows has either status_o1 or status_o2 as 'unpaid':

```
$rezultat = $polacz->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM skladki WHERE status_os1='unpaid' or status_os2='unpaid'");
$row = $rezultat ->fetch_assoc();
$wynik = $row["cnt"];
if($wynik==0)
{
    echo "You have all dues paid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM skladki WHERE status_os1 = "paid" and status_os2 = "paid"

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `CASE` expression in `COUNT()` like

```
SELECT 
COUNT(case when status_os1 = 'paid' and status_os2 = 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) 
FROM skladki;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery that filters out all records where, for that person or client, there is no record in the table with a value of 'Unpaid'.

```
Select * from table t
where not exists 
   (Select * from table
    Where id = t.Id
       and 'unpaid' in 
          (status_os1, status_os2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it from reverse side:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM skladki WHERE status_os1 = "unpaid" or status_os2 = "unpaid"
```

If there are at least 1 record - some record has unpaid status :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression to conditionally count all unpaid items. If 0 returned, return all dues paid message.

```
select case when count(case when status_os1 = 'unpaid' or status_os2 = 'unpaid' then 1 end) = 0 then 'You have all dues paid'
           else 'You have unpaid dues'
        end
from skladki
```